# Not Able to See Feature Layer With Different Spatial reference On the API Base Map

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I know ESRI is using following spatial reference for base maps

```
World_Street_Map (MapServer)
Spatial Reference: 102100  (3857) 
102100  (3857)
```

Now I have a feature layer which is already published in this spatial reference

> Spatial Reference: 102671  (3435)

after adding the fc to map like

```
  var fl= new FeatureLayer("http://devesri01.domain.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/ElectricVGA/FeatureServer/6");
  map.addLayer(fl);
```

but I am not seeing the layer in the map () No error Message either)? Do I have to publish the Future service with same spatial reference of the Base map?

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

- Substitute another Feature Layer Url in your code to confirm that
  works.
- Browse to the Url of your Feature Layer (http://devesri01
  ...FeatureServer/6) and ensure the Spatial Reference is defined in
  the Extent.
- Check for any scale dependencies on the layer (Min Scale, Max Scale)
  and ensure you zoom the map to the proper range.